# How do you populate a dropdown box from table data in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Controller:

```
public function create_form(){

    return view('propertys.create', array('user' => Auth::user())  );
}
```

I am pretty sure I need to make these changes and compact the fields in the view like so:

```
public function create_form(){
    $users = User::pluck('name', 'id');
    return view('propertys.create', array('user' => Auth::user()), compact('id', 'users')  );
}
```

But the how do I populate the Dropdown field in the form:

view:

```
...
    <input type="number" name="user_id">
...
```

I can't figure out how and there isn't any examples that I can locate that will work in Lavavel 5. They mostly use depreciated addons and code. So what is the easiest proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

Controller:

```
public function create_form(){
    $users = User::pluck('name', 'id');
    $Calle = Calle::all();
    $User = User::all();
    return view('propertys.create', array('user' => Auth::user()), compact('id', 'users'))->with('calle', $Calle)->with('user', $User);
}
```

And my form ended up looking like this:

```
...
    <select name="calle_id">
    @foreach($calle as $key => $value)
            <option value="{{ $value->id }}">{{ $value->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
    </select>
...
    <select name="propietario_id">
        @foreach($user as $key => $value)
            <option value="{{ $value->id }}">{{ $value->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
...
```

The key to it all was to setup my foreign key constraints properly like this:

```
class Property extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'propietario_id','id' );
    }
    public function calle(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Calle', 'calle_id','id' );
    }
}
```